# Is there any way to get Visual Studio 2008 to update .net style comments automatically?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, documentation-generation, xml-documentation

I've been writing a lot of VC++ 2008 / CLI software recently and am using the C#/CLI style documentation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Function the does stuff
/// </summary>
/// <param name="someParam">Specifies some option</param>
/// <returns>true if it worked</returns>
bool DoStuff( bool someParam );
```

I find myself re-typing those blocks quite frequently and frankly, it's getting repetitive. Is there any way to get Visual Studio to create / update those blocks automatically as you create new function definitions or update existing definitions?

Comment: Visual Assist ought to help: http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/documentMethod.asp

Comment: It's not for C++, but for C# and VB (just in case someone else finds this useful): GhostDoc, http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/documentMethod.asp) ought to help.

Comment: +1/Accepted: Thanks! I'd have preferred a free option, but I'll trial it and if it saves me some time then that's a business case right there :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check out my addin, [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/). It does all this and much much more.

(It also supports C++/CLI, C++, C#, Visual Basic and C)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you type a triple slash (///) at the beginning of a method VS will create a block for you.  You will have to supply the description of the function and parameters, though.  Not sure if there is a way to get it to auto-update.

Comment: That's a feature of the C# IDE.  The C++ IDE doesn't have it.